# What formal logic has the smallest metatheory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, philosophy, meta-math

I'm currently studying *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Third Edition) by Wolfgang Rautenberg. What sparked my interest in logic is my interest in *foundations* in general, so I was naturally pretty scandalized when I found out how classical first-order logic is developed and how its theorems (soundness and completeness, for example) are proved. The metatheory uses the metalogical implication $\Rightarrow$, proof by contradiction, proof by induction and even Zorn's lemma! That's not the bare-bones start I though I'd get the opportunity to examine!

I don't like that, since the goal of my study of the foundations of mathematics was to find out which concepts are the most fundamental in any formal system. Let me also note that a formal system I'm after must be sufficiently expressive (not something absurd like the empty set), meaning that it must be able to encode some useful theory (e.g., a part of mathematics or some other formal theory used in philosophy; mereology, the study of parts and its wholes, comes to mind). Thank you for your insights in advance! :)

Comment: Using first-order logic for foundational purposes does not require proving any theorems about it (or even having any metatheory at all, besides being able to algorithmically manipulate strings).  You just use it.

Comment: @EricWofsey A simple yet fantastic insight! Indeed, when I was reading some proofs of semantic equivalences, such as $\models \forall x(\alpha \land \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x\alpha \land \forall x\beta$, I kinda realized that I was just importing what I already knew about quantifiers on the metalogical level to my formal system.

Comment: You need to look into the works of Tarski, Kripke and others on [the semantics of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth). Tarski's paper *the Concept of Truth in Formalized Languages" is particularly relevant,  I think.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you! :)